# Example of a polycyclic group which is not of polynomial growth?

Tags: gr.group-theory, examples, geometric-group-theory

The title already says everything: What is an example of a polycyclic group $G$ which is not of polynomial growth (equivalently, by Gromov's theorem, which is not virtually nilpotent)?

Comment: I don't think that this is a research level question, but $\langle x,y,z \mid yz=zy, y^x=z, z^x=yz \rangle$ is such an example.

Comment: Note that Derek's example contains RW's example with index two (because the square of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semi-direct product of $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z^2$ determined by the matrix
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1  \\
1 & 1  \end{array} \right)$.